# Types of apps not suitable for react native on Android

Tags: android, react-native

I'm exploring using react native for a fairly complex android app. I was wondering what kind of apps are not suitable for react native? Or is the idea that you can do anything in React Native that you could do natively on Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the decision whether you should use React Native for your app, I would first check whether all the stuff (camera? location? toasts?) is covered by either React Native's own API's or a community created one.

If the answer is no, then you could also create your own, see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#content for isntructions.

Also know that you can build a "combo-app"; where part of the app is ran by React Native while the other part is truly native.

Comment: Thanks for replying Frederick and was hoping to ask a couple more specific questions. I was wondering about debugging.  My app is a bluetooth low energy app, so testing on a simulator will be limited. Do you know if when debugging a react native app on device, is it actually executing on the device or does it do some forwarding magic with chrome dev tools where it actually executes in chrome dev tools? Also, if one has a combo app, does debugging consist of debugging with chrome dev tools and android studio at the same time?

Comment: @MatthewChung you can run it directly on the device (and listen to logcat for console output), or debug in chrome. So both options are there. You can also disable all development settings to test how fast the app would run in real life (without all the development tools slowing you down). Finally, I don't know how to debug the combo apps; haven't done that myself yet..